# Write importable array to file in Bash?

Tags: bash, import, recording, array

I'm trying to make a high score system for a game I'm working on in Bash. So far what I've come up with is a system where I write a single array to a file and then just source it back afterwards. I'm currently trying to figure out how to write the array to the file such that it's easily source-able.

Problem is when I echo my array to the file it echos the "${highscores[@]}" literally instead of what is inside the highscores array. The code is as follows:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 #TODO Input an array from a file, read input from user, test if it's larger than any of the top 10, add it in there accordingly.
 #TODO Make it handle multiple high scores.
 num=0
 read -rp "enter score: " score
 if [ -f test.test ]; then
     . test.test
     for i in "{highscores[@]}"; do
         if [[ $score > $i ]]; then
             num=$((num+1))
             IFS=$'\n' highscores=($(sort <<<"${highscores[*]}"))
             highscores[$num]="$score"
             rm test.test #probably not best way of doing this
             echo 'highscores=( `"${highscores[@]}"` )' >> test.test

         else
             highscores+=("$score")
         fi
     done
     else
         highscores=( "$score" )
         echo 'highscores=( `"${highscores[@]}"` )' >> test.test
 fi
```

The part I'm specifically concer

```
echo 'highscores=( `"${highscores[@]}"` )' >> test.test
```

Despite the backticks it still doesn't actually print the contents of the array. Instead what it echos to the file is literally:

```
highscores=( "${highscores[@]}" )
```

If anyone has an easier or clearer way of doing this that would work too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how backticks work. Backticks run the *command* inbetween and expand to its *output*. If you merely put a variable expansion there, the shell will still try to *run* the expanded value as a command anyway.

Also, neither backticks nor variable expansions work at all inside single-quoted strings.

What you tried to do can be written as:

```
echo "highscores=( ${highscores[*]} )" > test.test

echo "highscores=(" "${highscores[@]}" ")" > test.test
```

But instead, you can just use:

```
declare -p highscores > test.test
```